# Anti-aliasing does not seem to work in Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, antialiasing

I was working fine with Android Emulator (on Manjaro Linux) a few weeks ago, but after updating software The GUI of Android Emulator is not rendering or anti-aliasing is not working anymore. My apps are displaying horrible texts.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm using `Hardware-GLES 2.0` for my graphic emulator.

Additional info:

[image]

[image]

Is there another alternative Android emulator working with Visual Studio Code?

---

**ANSWER**: Android Studio's Android emulator is not an efficient emulator, a better emulator is ***Genymotion***.

Answer (score 6):

I had a same problem. Downgrading Android Emulator to lower version solved the issue.

Latest version (before 30.9.5) that I could find was 30.8.4 with build id 7600983.

In order to downgrade firstly you will need to download the emulator. Here are the links for the version 30.8.4:

- Linux - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux_x64-7600983.zip
- MacOS - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_x64-7600983.zip
- Windows - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-7600983.zip

*You can also download even older versions here are [few alternatives](https://gist.github.com/0x0a0d/d3ce82f72e8f5681649b129d8a84e46b)*

After downloading the needed version of emulator you will need to unzip it.

The next thing is to replace your current emulator with new one.

1. Go to your Android Sdk folder (mine was *~/Android/Sdk*)
   `cd ~/Android/Sdk`
2. Rename your
   current emulator files folder. `mv emulator emulator.bak`
3. Copy new
   emulator
   `cp -r ~/Downloads/emulator-linux_x64-7600983/emulator/ .`
4. Replace package.xml file (otherwise Android Studio will not
   recognize your new emulator)
   `cp emulator.bak/package.xml emulator/package.xml`

Restart your Android Studio and Enjoy!

Comment: You're right. I tested this and it certainly improved. Android Studio is also failing to install intel HAXM. I thought the issue is due to that.

Comment: This fixed my issue! Damn, why does this bug even occur?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this issue was fixed with newest major 32 version of Android emulator.

Newest 32.1.6 and 32.1.7 Canary 1 versions behave like the things were before 30.9.5 which broke anti-aliasing completely for me on all Windows devices. I am using Hyper-V so HAXM is not available for me.

Emulators archive: https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive